# Can I stop all processes using CUDA in Linux without rebooting?

Tags: cuda, restart, kill-process

Is it possible to stop all running processing using the GPU via CUDA, without restarting the machine?

Comment: you could always change the permissions temporarily of /dev/nvidiaxx, I haven't tried it but I believe that would kill the jobs instantly. I don't know anyway of specifying jobs specifically running on the gpu unless you were using some kind of queue or load leveler.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The lsof utility will help with this.  You can get a list of processes accessing your NVIDIA cards with:

```
lsof /dev/nvidia*
```

Then use kill or pkill to terminate the processes you want.  Note that you may not want to kill X if it's running.  On my desktop system, both X and kwin are also accessing the GPU.

Comment: This does not work for me. Killing my kernel process has no effect. The kernel process is indefinitely consuming the GPU and I can't kill it.

Answer (score 16):

**Long answer:**

```
lsof /dev/nvidia*
```

gives you PIDs running on your GPU card which looks something like:
lsof: status error on PID: No such file or directory

```
COMMAND  PID    USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
python  7215 *******  mem    CHR 195,255           434 /dev/nvidiactl
python  7215 *******  mem    CHR   195,0           435 /dev/nvidia0
```

and

```
awk '{print $2}'
```

selects the PID column (in my case it is the second column) and

```
xargs -I {} kill {}
```

kills those PID jobs.

**Short answer:**

You may use the following command to remove them all at once.

**Watch out! This command will delete all PIDs showing up for lsof /dev/nvidia*. Do run lsof /dev/nvidia* first to confirm these jobs are the ones you want to delete.**

```
lsof /dev/nvidia* | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I {} kill {}
```

Finish the job by a single command.

Comment: Suggest you add a few lines about killing them dead with `kill -KILL` if they can't take a hint.

Comment: Good shit dude this just crashed my entire PC and Ubuntu went into repair mode upon startup

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I have changed the answer and add a reminder

Answer (score 13):

you can check the processes with `nvidia-smi` and then

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

Comment: Is it "kill -9 pid" ?  Cuz i tred kill -9 <pid>, and not working

Comment: I get it, just pid. <> is a like a quote

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fuser command to get the all the processes using CUDA and then kill them. There's also a nice single command to kill them all.

```
sudo fuser -k /dev/nvidia*
```

Comment: Note that unlike some other commands such as `kill`, the signal sent by `fuser -k` by default is `SIGKILL` instead of `SIGTERM`.